# C++ inheritance with templates in std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

So I have a class `Base` and a class `Derived: public Base`.

`baseInstance.doSomething()` will print `Base::doSomething()`.

`derivedInstance.doSomething()` will print `Derived::doSomething()`.

Here is the code:

```
#include "Base.h"
#include "Derived.h"
#include <vector>

int main(){
    Base base;
    std::cout<<"Base should do something:\n";
    base.doSomething();
    Derived derived;
    std::cout<<"\nDerived should do something:\n";
    derived.doSomething();
    std::vector<Base> vec;
    vec.push_back(derived);
    std::cout<<"\nDerived should do something:\n";
    vec[0].doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Base should do something:
Base::doSomething()

Derived should do something:
Derived::doSomething()

Derived should do something:
Derived::doSomething()
```

Actual output:

```
Base should do something:
Base::doSomething()

Derived should do something:
Derived::doSomething()

Derived should do something:
Base::doSomething()
```

How do I preserve class type in a `std::vector`?

EDIT:
But wouldn't the object slicing leave method implementation alone? And just remove excess fields?
And is there a way to circumnavigate this?

Comment: "And is there a way to circumnavigate this?" -- Don't copy a derived type into a base type and instead call through the base using a pointer (`Base*`) or reference (`Base&`).

Comment: FYI, in `C++` they are called templates not generics.

Comment: Sorry! Java-mind symptoms :)